# Change X,Y of view dynamically with animation android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am using [CursorWheelLayout](https://github.com/BCsl/CursorWheelLayout) library and in the Adapter i have created a view for every button , Now I want to move every button to the center button and make it disappear but it never works correctly for some reason ... this is the code i am using

```
private void startInvsibleAnimation(View view){
    //get the x and y i want the view to go to
    int[] location = new int[2];
    centerItem.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    Log.d("Debug","Center Item X: "+x+" Center Item Y: "+y);
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, x, 0, y);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            int[] location3 = new int[2];
            view.getLocationOnScreen(location3);
            int x2 = location3[0];
            int y2 = location3[1];
            Log.d("Debug","After Animation X: "+x2+" After Animation Y: "+y2);
        }
    });
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

and i have used this code:

```
    private void startInvsibleAnimation(View view){
    //get the x and y i want the view to go to
    int[] location = new int[2];
    centerItem.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    Log.d("Debug","Center Item X: "+x+" Center Item Y: "+y);
    view.animate().translationY(y);
    view.animate().translationX(x);
}
```

the animation never works see the bottom button always go down but should go up because the center item is above the view so what is the problem ?

the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKb8.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find diff between your `view` position and `centerItem` position and after that apply that diff to `view` via setting translations.

```
 private void startInvsibleAnimation(View view){
    //get the x and y i want the view to go to
    int[] location = new int[2];
    centerItem.getLocationOnScreen(location);

    int translationX = location[0] - view.getX();
    int translationY = location[1] - view.getY();
    
    view.animate().translationX(translationX ).translationY(translationY);    
}
```

Comment: show the place where you start your animation. Maybe you start it too early, i mean when view is not measured and all view sizes are zero

Comment: I have found the problem , I was trying to move a child inside the layout not the main layout , That caused the problem you saw ... and the code you provided was needed to move the view , Thanks for the help .